# Embedding and Displaying chinese/japanese

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, cjk

I have been working on a subtitles engine for flash/flv video player. On my Mac everything is great, nice aliased glyphs, displaying all the characters, etc. Switch to windows, it all goes out the window. Some machines with Eastern Characters enabled display fine, but I can't guarantee all users will have this option selected.

I am using the TLFTextField, I am pulling in UTF-8 XML with Chinese/Japanese characters.

I have tried embedding the (required fonts/glyphs) but pushes the file size up massively.

I have also tried changing it to unicode, with no joy. Has anyone got any experience with displaying these characters while maintaining a low file size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really offering a solution to your question, but if the user is wanting Chinese or Japanese subtitles, I'm pretty sure that they will have the correct encoding.

Comment: Thats true, yet there could be a scenario where a Chinese/Japanese reader would want to view it on a machine without the right encoding...

Comment: Yes, but it's probably a fringe case.  Then there's going to be a whole lot of text online that they can't read.  What I'm saying is that it's probably quite a low percentage that are going to have the problem, and they're probably having problems anyway, so it's probably not worth bothering everyone else with the burden of an inflated file size.

Comment: Good point! Ended up giving the Chinese/Japanese users the option to pull the required embedded fonts out of a separate swf (9mb each) and then renderes the subtitles nicely. Thanks tho Got to cater for those bloody fringes.